# Can't access aspx page after IIS reset using computer name only ip and localhost

Tags: iis-7, authentication, windows

After installing a fix in a site, and doing a iis reset we are unable to access (gets 401) the site using the computer name. Accessing using the ip-adress or localhost works fine, and it worked fine before the iis reset. Other sites on the same server workes the only difference is the port. Does anyone here had the same issue of can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still able to resolve an IP if you ping the name you are trying to connect to from another workstation because it sounds like a DNS issue. What version of IIS are you using? Have you checked to see what the host header value is for the other sites? Since you can access the problem site by IP, there is no host header value specified for the problem site. In IIS 6.0 open the IIS admin tool, right-click the website -> properties. click Advanced (next to the IP) and verify the host header values are correct. You should require host header values on all sites since most automated scanners scan by IP address and do not provide host header values unless you actually need to access the site via IP. It's a small step to drastically improve the security posture of your server.